# Difference Docker on bare metal and docker on ubuntu

Tags: docker

What is meant by Docker on bare metal? 
what is the difference between running docker on a ubuntu system and docker running on bare metal? 
Do we get all the features when running on bare metal?
how do I install Docker on bare metal?
Who runs the container?
Thanks!!

Comment: Where did you read that you can run Docker on bare-metal? As fas as I know you need to have at least a minimal [Linux System](https://docs.docker.com/installation/binaries) to run Docker. Otherwise you could not use the namespaces, bridge-utils usw..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Docker on bare metal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20088835/docker-on-bare-metal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker uses the linux-kernel to do containerization. Without a linux kernel it won't run.

Docker is only a go binary, and to run that you need an operating system .

Docker is often referred to be as fast as running on bare metal. In this context that means not to be in a virtual environment but to have an operating system.

Answer (score 2):

It's the same thing, bare metal just refers to the fact it is not running "in the cloud" or in a hypervisor or kvm. All the features are still the exact same. It is more referring to the setup of the server it is running on.