# Docker on bare metal (with some form of hypervisor) vs. on full fledged Linux distribution

Tags: docker

Is there any functionality difference in Docker when it runs on bare metal (with some form of hypervisor) as against when it runs on full fledged Linux distribution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Docker on bare metal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20088835/docker-on-bare-metal)

Answer (score 0):

Docker requires a Linux distribution to run on.  From the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/installation/binaries/):

> To run properly, docker needs the following software to be installed at runtime:
>
> - iptables version 1.4 or later
> - Git version 1.7 or later
> - procps (or similar provider of a "ps" executable)
> - XZ Utils 4.9 or later
> - a properly mounted cgroupfs hierarchy (having a single, all-encompassing "cgroup" mount point is not sufficient)

[...]

> In general, a 3.8 Linux kernel is the minimum requirement for Docker

Comment: If you want to put together such a system, I'd look at [boot2docker](http://boot2docker.io/). They've put together more-or-less what you're looking for: a tiny Linux VM capable of running Docker images. You could duplicate that on bare metal.